# managing files in docker container through env variables and a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, unix, environment-variables

so what am trying to do is to delete certain files based on the value of my environment variable through a script in a docker container

I run my dockerfile with my script included through CMD with the command "docker run -tid -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -e INDEX=1 --name {container name} {image name}"

here's my script file :

```
if "$INDEX" == 1
    rm var/www/index.nginx-debian.html && rm var/www/index.php && rm var/www/phpMyAdmin && rm var/www/wordpress
```

am not sure where my errors are, is the script doing what it should be doing (checking the env variable's value and acting accordingly) ? 
I do however know that my env variable got changed correctly when i exec the container i find it set to 1, its just that the files are not getting affected by the script
what can i possibly change to make sure the files i want deleted when a certain env variable value is true are actually deleted ?

Comment: [If statement bash scripting tutorial](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php) and other online resources on bash scripting will help you learn. You can remove multiple files with `rm` in a single line.

Comment: The combination of -itd isn't usually used since -d send the container to the background. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `-it` flags, inside the container, check if the files exist after you remove them

```
#############################################
# Inside your shell script in your container
#############################################
PATHSTOREMOVE="path1 path2 path3"
if [ "$INDEX" -eq "1" ]; then

    # ...code...

    rm ${PATHSTOREMOVE[@]}                       # Expansion syntax
    for PATH in $PATHSTOREMOVE; do
        if [ ! -f $PATH ]; then
            echo "Successfully removed $PATH"
        fi
    done

    # ...more code...

fi
```

Running your container with flags `-it` , you should see `Successfully removed <path>` for each path that does not exist anymore.